# C++ . Accessing Objects and Setting Values

Tags: c++, class, pointers, object

Hello StackOverflow community. 
I cant seem to change a value on a class.
I am new to C++, and I have been looking for a solution but I cant seem to figure it out.

```
This is my Account.cpp

    #include "Account.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



Account::Account(string accName, int accBalance)
{
    name = accName;
    balance = accBalance;
    std::vector<std::string> Report();

}


bool Account::Deposit(Account a,int amt) {
    if (amt >= 0) {
        a.balance += amt;
        return 1;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}

bool Account::Withdraw(Account a, int amt) {
    if (amt >= 0 && (a.balance - amt > 0)) {
        a.balance -= amt;
        return 1;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}

int equal(string a, string b) {
    if (a == b) return 1;
    else return 0;
}

Account::~Account()
{
}
```

This is my main.cpp

```
int main() {
int aux_bal;
string aux_name;
int choice;
std::string InputName;
std::list< Account > arr;
std::list<Account>::iterator result;

do
{


    cout << endl
        << " 1 - Create New Account.\n"
        << " 2 - View Balance.\n"
        << " 3 - Make a Deposit\n"
        << " 4 - Make a Withdraw\n"
        << " 5 - Check log\n"
        << " 6 - Exit.\n"
        << " Enter your choice and press return: ";
    cin >> choice;

    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
        cout << "Input holder's account name: \n";
        cin >> InputName;
        arr.push_back(Account(InputName, 0));


        break;
    case 2:
        cout << "Enter Account Name:\n";
        cin >> InputName;
        for (result = arr.begin(); result != arr.end(); result++) {
            int aux_bal = result->balance;
            std::string aux_name = result->name;
            if (aux_name == InputName) {
                cout <<"Account Balance:"<< aux_bal << endl;
                cout << "Account Holder:" << aux_name << endl;
            }
        }
            break;
    case 3:
        cout << "Enter Account Name:\n";
        cin >> InputName;
        for (result = arr.begin(); result != arr.end(); result++) {
            int aux_bal = result->balance;
            std::string aux_name = result->name;
            if (aux_name == InputName) {
                cout << "Enter ammount to Deposit:\n";
                cin >> aux_bal;
                (*result).Deposit(*result,aux_bal);
            }
        }
        break;
    case 4:
        //code to help the user like give him
        //extra information about the mode and the controller 
        break;
    case 5:

        break;
    case 6:cout << "End of Program.\n";
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Not a Valid Choice. \n"
            << "Choose again.\n";
        break;
        }

    } while (choice != 6);
    return 0;

}
```

For some reason when I output the account info after making a Deposit, the Balance value remains unaltered at 0.
Any help please?

Comment: You need to pass by reference. Passing by value means your function just alters its temporary copy of the object, so that change is not observable by the outside world. This is super basic C++, so consult your book in the first instance. But if you need an SO thread, there will be plenty, e.g. [function doesn't change object attributes in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42915874/function-doesnt-change-object-attributes-in-c)

Comment: Short answer: `Account::Deposit` and `Account::Withdraw` shouldn't take a second `Account` by value, they should operate on `this`. Long answer: don't model financial transactions by numerical balances, but as the sum of transaction objects

Comment: Wow, I didn't actually notice those were instance methods, not free functions. That's even worse. Sorry, but this is rudimentary stuff; please read a book before asking a question like this. If your book doesn't explain this nearly at the beginning, then get a better one.

Answer (score 0):

The deposit function should act on the account object that it belongs to, you don't need to pass it as an argument. Also, integers are not booleans. Lastly, why is the deposit amount an int? What if I want to deposit $20.25 ?

```
bool Account::Deposit(int depositAmt)
{
    if (depositAmt >= 0) {
        this->balance += depositAmt; // "this->" is optional
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: I'm just practicing so I didnt mind much on function types.
Thanks for the tips!

Comment: `this` is a pointer, so `this.` is a syntax error. The syntax would be `this->balance`, but the `this->` is implicitly searched for matching identifiers and so is technically redundant. Fwiw, opinions vary widely, but myself and others prefer to not write `this->` but instead prefix member variables with `m_` or similar. But that's been debated to death in other threads.