# I keep getting constant output for my depth function of a tree

Tags: c++, tree

I keep getting the initialized value of max as my output for some reason

```
/**
 * Definition for binary tree
 * struct TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode *left;
 *     TreeNode *right;
 *     TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(NULL), right(NULL) {}
 * };
 */
void maxi(struct TreeNode* A,int t,int k){
    if(A->left==NULL&&A->right==NULL&&t>k) k=t;
    if(A->left!=NULL) maxi(A->left,t+1,k);
    if(A->right!=NULL) maxi(A->right,t+1,k);
}

int Solution::maxDepth(TreeNode* A) {
    int l=0;
    maxi(A,1,l);
    return l;
}
```

The function keeps outputting initialized value of l. In this case 0.

Comment: Do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) of your code. Why do you expect the value of `l` to change?

Comment: Because I am updating its value in the maxi function.```if(A->left==NULL&&A->right==NULL&&t>k) k=t;``` Am I not? I'm sorry I'm new. So when it reaches a leaf node the value of ```l``` gets updated.

Comment: @ArminMontigny: Why would a correct answer that explains the problem _and_ solution be downvoted? (Hint, that's what that answer is)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [function doesn't change object attributes in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42915874/function-doesnt-change-object-attributes-in-c)